# docx2pdf close all the other word files that are opened

Tags: python, ms-word, docx2pdf

I am currently using the docx2pdf library in Python to convert Word files to PDF format. However, I have noticed that when I execute the conversion process, it forcibly closes all other Word files that I may have open for editing. Is there a way to prevent this behavior, or are there alternative libraries that I can utilize for this conversion task? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

```py
from docx2pdf import convert
# Specify the input and output file paths
input_file = self.nameProject + '.docx'
current_directory = os.getcwd()
output_file = os.path.join(current_directory, self.nameProject + '.pdf')

# Convert the file and save it to the specified output path
convert(input_file, output_file)
```

Comment: I see you already posted a Github issue, but one of the other issues there suggests that `keep_active` prevents the library from closing other documents (see https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf/issues/60).

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, I've found that win32com works for me, leaving open Word windows untouched:

```
from win32com import client
# Specify the input and output file paths

# Convert the file and save it to the specified output path
doc = client.GetObject(input_file)
doc.SaveAs(output_file, FileFormat=17)
```

This sort of thing works too:

```
from win32com import client
# Specify the input and output file paths

word = client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = True
doc = word.Documents.Open(str(input_file))
# make edits etc
doc.SaveAs(str(output_file), FileFormat=17)
doc.Save
doc.Close() # etc
```

N.B. Converting Path objects to string (I was using pathlib)